# symfony search form keep seach parameters

Tags: forms, search, symfony5

I made a searchform, but i don't know how to keep the selected search parameters in the form.
I would like to do this through the controller and not in twig file self.
I thought by setting the parameter it will preselect the option but that doesn't work.

Below my form

```
    $builder

    ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Producttype::class,

        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC');
        },

        'choice_label' => 'Title',
        'placeholder' => 'All types',
        'required'   => false,
    ])

    ->add('Search', SubmitType::class)
    ;

}
```

In the controller I have this

```
$query = $request->query->get('searchfilter');

$querybuilder = $em->getRepository(Product::class)
->createQueryBuilder('p');


if($query['type'] != NULL) {
    $querybuilder->innerJoin('p.producttype', 'b')
    ->addSelect('b')
     
    
    ->andWhere('b.id like :type')
    ->setParameter('type', $query['type']);
    ;
}
```

and the form in twig

```
<div class="container">
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('product_search'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
   {{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can acheive this by using session

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback.  Yes sessions works fine. I put it in the twig file see below. <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="searchfilter[type] ">

 {% for child in form.type %}

    <option 

    {% if type is defined %}

       {% if type == child.vars.value %} selected{% endif %}

       {% endif %} value="{{ child.vars.value }}">{{ form_label(child) }}</option>

    {% endfor %}

 </select>


But I was wondering if I can also give the selected value in the controller already.